# Django ViewSet returns result in command line, provides error when visiting URL

Tags: python, django

I have a viewset set up like so:

**views.py**

```
class TalentView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'talent.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = CampaignTalent.objects.filter(campaign_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return query
```

**models.py**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class CampaignTalent(models.Model):
    talent_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    talent_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    approved = models.BooleanField()
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(
        'Campaign',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I am trying to provide the viewset a list of talent attached to the campaign, given by the `PK`. When I log out in my console the results of `query` into my console I get `<QuerySet [<CampaignTalent: CampaignTalent object (1)>]>`, however my page returns a 404 with the error `No campaign talent found matching the query`. Even if I log out the raw query and run it against my DB, I get results.

Why am I receiving a `No ... found matching query` response?

Comment: Could you provide your urls.py and also the URL you are trying to reach?

Comment: From what I can tell, the issue was that this view was a Detail View, but I was returning a list of results - I'm not sure if thats the right answer but I changed from `DetailView` to `ListView` and its working now